# Why does my joystick keep acting like a mouse?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, joystick

Why does my my joystick keep acting like a mouse?

My joystick is a bluetooth 8BitDo NES 30 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem here, it was simply I disable the control in the Xinput list, in case the commands I used were `xinput list` to see the ID of my controller and `xinput disable *ID*` to "disable it" and, although the control is "disabled", its buttons and analog function normally, but do not move the mouse anymore

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to make it permanent? Power cycling the controller and reconnecting to the Bluetooth system requires me to run these again.