# Bluetooth Asus gamepad controlling mouse & keyboard input, unwanted

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, asus, gamepad

I recently purchased an Asus gamepad for Nexus Player - I didn't notice the Nexus bit until I checked the packaging for more info for this post (that might be part of my problem) - and the gamepad controls my mouse and certain keys. I have tried a variety of programs to remove those functions; I only want it working with my Steam games.

I have tried using xboxdrv & ubuntu-xboxdrv via the instructions on this reddit page:

[xboxdrv config for ASUS Nexus Bluetooth gamepad](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/2x2ts8/xboxdrv_config_for_asus_nexus_bluetooth_gamepad)

I tried jstest-gtk and antimicro (based on a page I found on this site), but I couldn't see anyway to disconnect the mouse & keys from the gamepad. I also tried to uninstall xserver-xorg-input-joystick, but it seems it wasn't even installed.

The only thing I found that helped was the answer on this page:

[Why does my joystick keep acting like a mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962524/why-do-my-joystick-keeps-acting-like-a-mouse/962637#962637)

xinput list gave me:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ USB Wired Keyboard                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ LXD Gaming Mouse                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ USB Wired Keyboard                        id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ ASUS Gamepad                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So I input:

```
xinput disable 11
```

It half worked, removing only the mouse functions. That would have been fine, as I can now play my games without looking at my feet every 5 seconds, except the gamepad's start and back buttons aren't working at all in-game, and every time my gamepad restarts I have to disable it again.

Comment: This is ancientspirit, I'm not sure if I'm signed in or not (stack exchange is giving me problems on my mobile). I'm a new user on AskUbuntu and I don't know how to format stuff properly and appreciate the help, though I find odd to fix the grammar of the hyperlink title of another person's post.

Comment: I thought you had fixed the grammar? I went and fixed the title of the other post so that it would not require correcting in your question :)

Comment: Lol, okay, that makes more sense.